# Keyboard shortcut: Changing Focus Term to VLC 14.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, window, focus

I'm viewing  a Python tutorial  using VLC as the viewer.
At the same time I'm encouraged to have a Python terminal or IDLE open and be working in the term. 
Question is:  are there any keyboard short-cuts to change focus from term to VLC so that I can stop the playback and go back to Term to practice exercises and then change focus again.
 Keyboard media buttons on Logitech K-360 are not operable though I've tried to make them function under settings/keyboard/short-cuts
 I keep the VLC player full screen with Term "keep on top" as a small window .
 The only way I've found so far is mousing from one to another to change focus and make either operable.Looked around quite a bit and tried various but no joy.
[image]
Screenshot of my screenview.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why don't you use the good old `Alt + Tab`

Maybe I misunderstood the question but it looks like what you describe is this.

Comment: When I had tried Alt + Tab it offered and switched between 6 different options;  Realize now that these were other open windows. Key is have only 2 focus targets  available and focus changes just fine.

Comment: The way Alt +Tab works is actually to make you switch between the two most recent tabs. Even if there is other tabs, if you switch from IDE to VLC using Alt+Tab, when you use it on VLC it'll send you back to IDE.